# jQuery Pagination - limiting the number of rows per page

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am trying to get the data using `AJAX` method. I m not sure how to limit the number of rows per page. How can we paginate using `jQuery`? Can you suggest me some easy method on limiting the number of rows per page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var tr;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].userId + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].title + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].body + "</td>");
        $('#table').append(tr);                      
      }
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id = "numbers"></div>
  <input type="button" id="addr" value="Add Data" />
  <h5>Table Data</h5>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>userId</th>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>body</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How many datas you want to display on a page?

Comment: I want to display 10 per page

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery](https://datatables.net/). It is flexible and powerful, also you will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do pagination on the server side, but if you didn't make the endpoint or want to do it front end you'll have to count the results and create link to the pages dynamically, and then create function that runs when you click each page link that will re-run the ajax request and pass it an argument of what page they clicked.   Something like this:

```
function(pageNum) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var tr;
      for (var i = (pagenum - 1) * 10; i < pagenum * 10; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].userId + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].title + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].body + "</td>");
        $('#table').append(tr);                   
      }
    }
  });
}
```